# how to incorporate dynamic column name in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table, which has columns, say 
Week1,Week2, Week3 and so on.

I have a stored procedure, and based on the number input, i want to select that column.

Example, if input is 4 then I want to make the query,

```
select * 
from table_name 
where Week4=<something>
```

Is there any way to do this other than using dynamic query? Because this dynamic thing will be just a small part of a huge query.

Comment: Can you change the database? If you had a properly normalized database model this wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name **IS RIGHT**. What happens when the database is in production after 2 years? You have 104 columns. 3 years - 156 columns. That's really, really bad design. If even remotely possible, you should normalize this.

Answer (score 0):

The comments about normalization are right, but if you have no choice, you can use "or" clauses:

```
declare @inputvalue int;
set @int = 1;

select *
  from <table>
 where (week1 = <something> and @inputvalue = 1)
    or (week2 = <something> and @inputvalue = 2)
    or (week3 = <something> and @inputvalue = 3)
    or (week4 = <something> and @inputvalue = 4)
```

This will be very slow if the tables are of any size, as you won't be using any indexes.  I wouldn't suggest doing this unless you're absolutely unable to change the table structure.

Comment: Why are you showing SQL-Server syntax for an Oracle question?

Comment: My bad; I missed the Oracle tag.  I no longer recall the Oracle syntax but I would assume the same approach, using "or", would work.  Though it is a horrible way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't what you asked for, but I figured I'd point out to some people who find this what you mean by doing this as a dynamic query.

You'd just write a procedure and hold the field name in there. Assuming that the naming standard is the same, so the input value would be the week# (1,2,7,27, 123, etc.) and the field name would directly correspond (Week1, Week2, Week7, Week27, Week123, etc.)

```
create or replace procedure myweek(week_in varchar2)
is
dyn_sql varchar2(1000);
begin
dyn_sql := 'select * from table_name where week'||week_in||' = ''something;'' '
execute immediate dyn_sql;
end;
/
```

Then to call it you'd just do something like :

```
exec myweek(27); and it would generate the sql:
select * from table_name where week27 = 'something';
```